# how to deal with competing risk of death in the cox regression

Tags: cox-model, competing-risks

I have a data which is set up for cox regression, I have the variable as below:

```
Tstart, Tstop, status event, cancer, family id,
```

The `status event` variable contains 0, 1 and 2. This shows that 0 no event, 1 ability decline happened as event,and 2 means death (competing risk of death). Since my interest is only to look at ability decline in cancer and nocancers. Should I only keep in the regression below `"status event"` as zero and one. And, excluding death?

coxph(Surv(Tstart, Tstop, status event ~ cancer+ cluster(family id)), data = d[!d$status event==2,])

Is it the correct way to consider competing risk of death?

Comment: @EdM you are the best who can help

Comment: To be interested in the risk of declining, accounting for death as a competing risk, you must be interested in the somewhat strange question of how the risk of declining **that precedes death** varies with $X$.  Is that really what you want (vs. a state transition model)?

Comment: @ 
Frank Harrell
because I am looking into old people, i need to consider for competing risk of death.  For all that event happened there is no death before the event. Then I look on those that event has not happened and they died.

Comment: That makes sense but if you look a the question from the standpoint of time zero, competing risk analysis is trying to estimate a type of conditional probability (chance of declining before dying) whereas state transition models are estimating simple unconditional probabilities (chance of declining or dying; chance of dying, chance of declining and not dying).

Comment: @
Frank Harrell
thanks. Do you mean using multistate modelling? The problem is that i need to use at some point stratified cox model. And I am not sure how to do this in R usign "mstate" package.

Comment: `mstate` is especially good for discrete time multi-state modeling.  The `survival` package in R (which you are already using) handles continuous-time multistate modeling.  See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf .  But in many cases a multi-state ordinal longitudinal model has the simplest interpretation: https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19 and especially https://www.fharrell.com/talk/rcteff/

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence, but Frank Harrell is _much_ more of an expert on this. Note that pinging with `@` only works for someone who is already involved in the thread; I just happened to come upon this question while browsing. I would also recommend the competing-risks vignette he linked.